# Redirect everything to www on Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, ssl, https

So I am trying to make everything redirect to `https://www`.

I want all these to redirect to this `https://www.website.com`

```
http://website.com
http://www.website.com
https://website.com
```

So lets say you are on `https://www.website.com` and then you remove `www` from the url so it looks like `https://website.com`. Instead of just showing the website without `www` I want it to put the `www` back in the url.

So basically I want it to always have `www` no matter what.

Whats the best way to go about doing this? Redirct, mod_rewrite, etc. I have access to the root configuration so I don't need to use .htaccess

Additional info that might help solve this.

```
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I figured it out. I'll leave the config in case anyone else has the same question.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName website.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

Redirect permanent / https://www.website.com/

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>

ServerName https://www.website.com/
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com$1  [L]

</VirtualHost>
```